# How to print set of input boxes which have same input name into div onKeyUP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input boxes set to enter fname lname, there are 10 boxes with these input names. And i want to print the value onKeyup to a div. Please advise.

```
<input required class="special-block" type="text" name="fname[]"  class="fname" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML = this.value" placeholder="Name" />
<input required class="special-block" type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5a').innerHTML = this.value"  />
```

### values should display here

```
<p id="refa5"><span class="fname"></span>-<span class="lname"></span></p>
```

Comment: pls show me your full code

Comment: @AzeezKallayi : whole code isbit lengthy. I have 10 input fields with holding name as fname lname, and below has add button where user can add new input fields as well. but all having same input name one is fname and other is lname. there is option to print form . so im storing values to a div whenver user types. pls advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate `current html` with `previous html` using `+ operator`.
So change

```
onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML = this.value"
```

To

```
onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+= this.value"//concatenates with previous html
```

So

```
<input required class="special-block" type="text" name="fname[]"  class="fname" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5').innerHTML+= this.value" placeholder="Name" />
<input required class="special-block" type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Designation" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('refa5a').innerHTML+= this.value"  />
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hek_Mat/9gobLbr3/4/) based on comments.

Comment: I checked the fiddle but it repeates the values which i enter. :(

Comment: Then what you want..separate by what?

Comment: Best way is use `onblur` event(triggers when you leave text field). And also concatenates with sapce.see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Hek_Mat/9gobLbr3/3/

Comment: I want something like fname-lname </br> fname-lname

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lots